# [Proof Verification]: Closure of a set is the union of the set with its boundary.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $A$ a subset of $X$. I want to show that $\bar{A}= A \cup \partial A$.

My proof probably isn't the simplest, but I'm just beginning to write proofs seriously and I want to know if this one holds up. I'll show one inclusion here but the other is almost identical.

Suppose $x\in\bar{A}$ but $x\not\in A \cup \partial A$. Then since $x\not\in\partial A$, there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ which either does not intersect $A$ or $X\setminus A$. Since $x\in \bar{A}$, every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, so $N$ must not intersect $X\setminus A$. But this is absurd, since $x\in X\setminus A$.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of the closure, which is sometimes the union of interior and boundary, or the intersection of all closed sets which contain it, or.... Usually the statement "every neighbourhood intersects..." is proven from the definition of closure.

Comment: But if you're using that statement as your definition of closure then this proof looks good.

Comment: In the book they define the closure of a set as the intersection of all closed sets which contain it, but then prove a point is in the closure iff every neighbourhood contains some point of the set.

Comment: Then that would be fine. I believe you can prove this statement without using that result, but it's an equivalent characterisation so there's no problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit roundabout, as you say, but it looks OK. I'd prove it like this (no proof from contradiction): let $x \in \overline{A}$. If $x \in A$ we're done: $x \in A \cup \partial A$, and if not, every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ (from being in its closure) and $X\setminus A$ (in $x$ itself at least), so $x \in \partial A$ and we're done too. Same arguments in a more "positive" form.

The reverse is similar: if $x \in A \cup \partial A$, then $x \in A \subseteq \overline{A}$ and we're done or $x \in \partial A \subseteq \overline{A}$ (if every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects both $A$ and its complement, a fortiori every neighbourhood intersects $A$) and we're done again.